# Проверить состояние потока и вернуть из него результат?

Tags: python, многопоточность, zmq

Нужно в в одной функции запустить другую, в которой происходит подключение с помощью zmq к другому компьютеру. Необходимо вызвать функцию подключения, подождать секунд 10 и, если успешно подключилось, взять результат из функции подключения, если она не подключилась, то выкинуть ошибку.  Кусок функции, в которой вызываю функцию подключения:

```
result =["fail"]
t = Thread(target= ping_function, args=(conn_str, task.task_json))
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
                    
if t.is_alive() == True:
    ret = "is alive"
    t.join()
```

Функция подключения:

```
def ping_function(conn_str, json):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect(conn_str)
    socket.send_json(json)
    socket.recv_json()
    result[0] = "good"
    return("good")
```

Не совсем понимаю, как надо делать, нигде не смогла найти объяснение по моей ситуации, не судите строго)

Answer (score 2):

```
return = 1
```

это синтаксическая ошибка.

из потока можно вернуть результат используя список.

```
result = ["fail"]

def ping_function(conn_str, json):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect(conn_str)
    socket.send_json(json)
    socket.recv_json()
    result[0] = "good"
    return

t = Thread(target= ping_function, args=(conn_str, task.task_json))
t.start()
time.sleep(10)
                    
if t.is_alive() == True:
    ret = "is alive"
    t.join()

print(result[0])
```

а еще можно воспользоваться ThreadPoolExecutor из concurrent.futures

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()


def ping_function(conn_str, json):
    try:
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        socket.connect(conn_str)
        socket.send_json(json)
        socket.recv_json()
    except Exception:
        state = "error"
    else:
        state = "good"
    return state


feature = pool.submit(ping_function, conn_str, task.task_json)
result = feature.result(10)

print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я исправила (что-то случился затуп). Как получить этот результат в главной функции?

Comment: в первом случае список это глобальный объект. так что после завершения потока просто обратитесь к первому элементу списка.

Comment: поток может не остановиться, в этом и суть. Надо прервать его выполнение, если он дольше, например, 10 сек

Comment: к сожалению прервать поток в пайтон из вне не возможно. если в потоке есть блокирующий вызов который залипает. в даном случае я вижу что идет общение по сокету, а сокету можно задать таймаут. так и решится проблема с прерыванием потока)

Comment: спасибо, я попробую)